# Remove Comma from Values added to Hidden Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

how can i replace the commas with space between?
I am using this snippet for adding values of checkboxes to a hidden field.

reference: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/jquery-multiple-checkbox-values-to-comma-separated-string-1105.aspx

current results looks like this:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="textValue" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7" />
```

I want to have following result

```html
<input type="hidden" id="textValue" value=" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7" />
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">

        <input type="checkbox" name="swimmingpool" id="swimmingpool" value="1" />

        Swimming Pool<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="fitnesscenter" id="fitnesscenter" value="2" />

        fitness center<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="restaurant" id="restaurant" value="3" />

        restaurant<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="childrenactivities" id="childrenactivities" value="4" />

        children’s activities<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="complimentarybreakfast " id="complimentarybreakfast"

            value="5" />

        complimentary breakfast<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="meetingfacilities" id="meetingfacilities" value="6" />

        meeting facilities<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="petsallowed " id="petsallowed " value="7" />

        pets allowed<br />

        <input type="hidden" id="txtValue">

</div>
```

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

function updateTextArea() {

            var allVals = [];

            $('#mydiv :checked').each(function () {

                allVals.push($(this).val());

            });

            $('#txtValue').val(allVals)
        }

        $(function () {

            $('#mydiv input').click(updateTextArea);

            updateTextArea();

        });

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this:

replace
`$('#txtValue').val(allVals)`
with
`$('#textValue').val(allVals.join(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
$('#txtValue').val(allVals)
```

Do this:

```
$('#txtValue').val(allVals.join(" "))
```

`join` converts an array to a string, separating each value by the separator you pass as the argument to `join`, in this case a space.